# How to Correctly Write this Arithmatic Expression in Bash / Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I cannot somehow make this work,

```
(( chunks = $size / $chunk_size + 1 ))
echo $chunks
```

**EDIT**

---

I have also tried,

```
chunks = $(( $size / $chunk_size + 1 ))
```

---

Although this works,

```
while [ $counter -le 10 ]; do
    echo $counter;
    (( counter++ ))
done
```

The former gives me `/ 157286400 + 1 ")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "` and the error itself is not nicely formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$size` variable is not initialized or has other, non-numeric characters in it.

```
$ chunk_size=157286400
$ unset size
$ (( chunks = $size / $chunk_size + 1 ))
-bash: ((: chunks =  / 157286400 + 1 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ 157286400 + 1 ")
$ size=$'\r'  # carriage return
$ (( chunks = $size / $chunk_size + 1 ))
 / 157286400 + 1 ")syntax error: operand expected (error token is "
```

You can remove the carriage return by modifying your AWK command like this:

```
awk '/^Content-Length:/ { gsub("\015", "", $2); print $2 }'
```

Comment: Yes, `$size` may have other non-numeric whitespaces. I am doing a `detected_size=$( echo "$header" | awk '/^Content-Length:/ { print $2 }' )` where $header is an HTTP header. Any suggestions on how to fix it? Many thanks.

Comment: @Hindol: You can remove the carriage return by modifying your AWK command like this: `awk '/^Content-Length:/ { gsub("\015", "", $2); print $2 }'`

Comment: Yes it works, :). Can you update your answer to reflect this? Others may find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure $size and $chunk_size are initialized...
Tested:

```
size=1
chunk_size=2
(( chunks = $size / $chunk_size + 1 ))
echo $chunks
```

Comment: They are both initialized, still not working. `echo $size` and `echo $chunk_size` both print non-zero values.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let size=10
let chunk_size =2
declare -i chunks
let chunks =  $(($size / $($chunk_size + 1))))
echo $chunks
```